# Django Test Runner Not Finding Test Methods

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I recently upgraded from Django 1.4 to 1.9 and realized something weird was going on with my tests. Here is the project structure:

```
project
  manage.py
  app/
    __init__.py
    tests/
      __init__.py
      test_MyTests.py
```

The test_MyTests.py file looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_math(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)

    def test_math_again(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, 3)
```

The test runner can find all of the tests when I run
`./manage.py test app` or `./manage.py test app.tests`. However when I try running `./manage.py test app.tests.MyTests` I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in    loadTestsFromName
parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyTests'
```

If I change the test class name to test_MyTests I can then run `./manage.py test app.tests.test_Mytests` and it will find all tests. I was reading the Django docs though and it seems the file name and class name don't have to be the same. In either case that I showed above I still can't run individual tests like this, `./manage.py test app.tests.MyTests.test_math`

I would like to be able to run individual tests and test classes, can someone help me here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app.tests.test_MyTests` part `test_MyTests` is module name, not class. To run `test_math` you should specify full path to this method:

```
python manage.py test app.tests.test_MyTests.MyTests.test_math
```

Answer (score 0):

Y had the same problem and it was that I forgot to remove the default file **tests.py** that django create automatic when you create the app.